# How can navigate one level back at the git interactive staging (add) command

Tags: git, staging, git-add, git-stage, git-index

After running the interactive staging git command `$ git add -i` and choosing one of the options for example "update", then I don't know how to get back to the root level to choose another option.

Is there any keyboard shortcuts or alternative methods rather that just using "ctrl + c" and then running the code `$ git add -i`, again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press `?` while interactive adding you can see that help:

```
Prompt help:
1          - select a single item
3-5        - select a range of items
2-3,6-9    - select multiple ranges
foo        - select item based on unique prefix
-...       - unselect specified items
*          - choose all items
           - (empty) finish selecting
```

So basically just press enter, it should return to main selection

Comment: Oh thanks. it's really helpful, exactly what i need!!!!!!!
but can i ask where did u find the solution from?

Comment: By trials and errors ;)
I just run `git add -i`, selected update, tried `help` and `help?` with no luck and then tried `?`

Comment: Oh great, thank you